# php from command line empty

Tags: php, windows, command-line-interface

I have updated windows today and now when I use the command line and type PHP nothing returns. tried various PHP commands, nothing, not even an error or response. blank.

I had the correct path in the environment variables. Tried to change to another PHP version and even tried removing the path from environment variables but still returns empty!
It doesn't even say that "PHP" is not recognized although I removed the environment variable!!

I have no clue how to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not passing extra parameters when you call it from command line, that´s how it supposed to work.

Try running:

```
php --help (to see all options from command line)
```

Also, to make sure it is running try to do this:

```
php -v (to check version)
php -F filename.php
```

The last one should run your php file.

Comment: php -v or any other command did not return anything. I had to remove the php7 env path from the system variables, and add a php 5.6 env path to the user. It seems I have a probem with php7. It use to work before update. Any way to fix this? i would like to use php 7

Comment: It doesn´t return anything or returns some error? Nothing returned means it was running php7 binary, right?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same challenge. 
Here's a solution:

1. Use a standard terminal window (instead of Powershell).
2. Try php -v again.
3. IF you get an error mentioning VCRUNTIME140.dll
4. THEN you need to install run-time components that are required to run C++ applications built using Visual Studio 2015 here:  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145